# Remove template type from templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have this structure:

```
template <typename T>
using AllSettings = std::variant<
    A<T>,
    B<T>,
    C<T>,
    D<T>
>;

template typename<T>
void Foo() {
    using SettingClassT = std::variant_alternative_t<0, AllSettings<T>>;

    //....
}
```

is it possible to obtain base class without `<T>` from the `SettingClassT`?
Something like this:

```
template <typename T>
using SettingClassBase = ... somehow remove T from SettingClassT
```

Because I need to call other template method that expects base type and `T` type separatelly.

```
template <template<class> class Base, typename T>
void Bar() { }
```

so I can call:

```
Bar<SettingClassBase, T>();
```

Comment: Have you tried a macro?

Comment: I am not sure whether this is what you want but in `A`, `B` etc. you can have: `template<class T> struct { using template_type = T; }; ` and then just pass `Bar<B<T>, B<T>::template_type>` but that would be a bit strange....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about what do you exactly want but... seems to me that you're looking for a template struct as `getTemplatePar`

```
template <typename>
struct getTemplatePar;

template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
struct getTemplatePar<C<T>>
 { 
   template <typename U>
   using baseType = C<U>;
 };
```

so you can write `Foo()` as follows (thanks to Evg and cigien for the `template` correction):

```
template <typename T>
void Foo()
 {
   using SettingClassT = std::variant_alternative_t<0, AllSettings<T>>;

   Bar<getTemplatePar<SettingClassT>::template baseType, T>();
 }
```

Comment: `getTemplatePar<SettingClassT>::template baseType`

Comment: @Evg - Are you sure it's necessary that `template`? My example compile, with g++ and clang++, without it (but I admit that never understand when `template` is necessary and when it isn't)

Comment: GCC fails without `template`: https://godbolt.org/z/8h973eznT

Comment: See @Evg's demo. I'm pretty sure the template is required. I think your test with Clang is compiling because you don't instantiate `Foo` perhaps?

Comment: @cigien - Exactly: I didn't instantiate `Foo()`. Instantiating it I get an error from both g++ and cang++. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @Evg - You're right. As cigien supposed, I didn't instantiate `Foo()`. Corrected. Thanks.